# Combining OnsenUI app and Wordpress website

Tags: php, wordpress, onsen-ui

I have a webapp that I created using OnsenUI and hosted on AWS. My company website is based on WordPress and now I would like to combine the two, if you will, to use one domain. That would require me to somehow transfer my webapp, if possible, or at least the html files and all required libraries/files (CSS, JS, etc.) to my WordPress site - NOT replacing current Wordpress site, just wanting to add the webapp as a page. The motivation behind moving the webapp to WordPress is so that I am able to implement a paywall. Any suggestions? I’ve never programmed in PHP and overall still a novice with WordPress. **Please help, pretty much at end of rope.**